# Regex to match an aws arn

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate aws arn for a connect instance but I am stuck on creating the correct regex.

Below is the string that I want to validate.

```
arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:123456789011:instance/0533yu22-d4cb-410a-81da-6c9hjhjucec4b9
```

I want to create a regex which checks below things.

```
arn:aws:connect:<region_name>:<12 digit account id>:instance/<an alphanumeric instance id>
```

Can someone please help.

Tried below

```
^arn:aws:connect:\S+:\d+:instance\/\S+\/queue\/\S+$
```

Comment: What effort have you made?

Comment: already for the fist matching sequence the OP does not want to match non whitespace characters since `:` would be included, but the OP wants to match anything which is not a `:` ... thus `([^:]+):` instead of `\S+`

Comment: [`^(?:\w+:){3}(?<region>[^:]+):(?<accountId>\d{12}):instance\/(?<instanceId>.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/rwIKR6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `/queue/` substring in your example string, and `\S+` matches any no whitespace character and will cause backtracking to match the rest of the pattern.

You might update your pattern to `^arn:aws:connect:\S+:\d+:instance\/\S+$` but that will be less precise according to the things you want to check.

A bit more precise pattern could be:

```
^arn:aws:connect:\w+(?:-\w+)+:\d{12}:instance\/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `arn:aws:connect:` Match literally
- `\w+(?:-\w+)+:` Match 1+ word characters and repeat matching `-` and 1+ word characters and then match `:`
- `\d{12}:` Match 12 digits and `:`
- `instance\/` Match `instance/`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+` Match 1+ alpha numerics and repeat 1+ times `-` and 1+ alpha numerics
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSToPo/1)

Comment: According to AWS stream name regex should be `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+`, `^arn:aws:connect:\w+(?:-\w+)+:\d{12}:instance\/[A-Za-z0-9_.-]++$` is correct.  See "StreamName" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStream.html

Answer (score 1):

You need some capture groups to facilitate this. Here I've also used [named capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) for ease of understanding.

```js
const string = "arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:123456789011:instance/0533yu22-d4cb-410a-81da-6c9hjhjucec4b9";

// Regex broken down into parts
const parts = [
  'arn:aws:connect:',
  '(?<region_name>[^:]+?)',         // group 1
  ':',
  '(?<account_id>\\d{12})',         // group 2
  ':instance\\/',
  '(?<instance_id>[A-z0-9\\-]+?)',  // group 3
  '$'
];

// Joined parts into regex expression
const regex = new RegExp(parts.join(''));

// Execute query and assign group values to variables
const { region_name, account_id, instance_id } = regex.exec(string).groups;

console.log("region_name:", region_name);
console.log("account_id:", account_id);
console.log("instance_id:", instance_id);
```